# Mail from contact form without date

Tags: php, email, date, contact-form

after many trials and errors i finally got a php contact form working the way i want, sending the correct information to my hosting mail address. And all appears well except for the Date, it doesn't appear at all (on my inbox). I already contacted the hosting service but they didn't replied. I've also went researching the php manual but there's almost no info about the Date atribute/header. Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Here is my php:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

foreach( $_POST as $value ){
if( stripos($value,'Content-Type:') !== FALSE ){
echo "There seems to be something wrong with your information. Please try again.";
exit;
}
}

if ($_POST["morada"] != "") {
    echo "Oops! Error. Please try again.";
    exit;
}

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "main@myemailaccount.com";
$email_subject = "Contact Form";


// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['nome']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['phone']) ||
    !isset($_POST['website']) ||
    !isset($_POST['motivo']) ||
    !isset($_POST['mensagem'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
}

$nome = $_POST['nome']; // required
$email = $_POST['email']; // required
$phone = $_POST['phone']; // required
$website = $_POST['website']; // not required
$motivo = $_POST['motivo']; // required
$mensagem = $_POST['mensagem']; // required
$error_message = "";

$email_message = "Form details below.<br><br>";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Nome: ".clean_string($nome)."<br>";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."<br>";
$email_message .= "Telefone: ".clean_string($phone)."<br>";
$email_message .= "Website: ".clean_string($website)."<br>";
$email_message .= "Motivo: ".clean_string($motivo)."<br>";
$email_message .= "Mensagem: ".clean_string($mensagem)."<br><br><br><br>";

$email_message = wordwrap($email_message, 70);

// create email headers
$headers =  "";
$headers .= 'From: '.$nome.'<'.$email.'>'.$eol;
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$nome.'<'.$email.'>'.$eol;
$headers .= 'Return-Path: '.$nome.'<'.$email.'>'.$eol;
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion().$eol;
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'.$eol;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8".$eol;


@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
    {
      echo header("Location: thanks.html");
    }}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't have a server configured with a mailing engine so I can't test it. But I think you just need to add the 'Date' header:

```
$headers .= 'Date: '.date('r').$eol;
```

You might want to configure a default time zone:

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, i added those 2 lines on my code but it didn't work, i still get the mail with the date in blank. I'm using roundcube email account as my inbox. Do you think it might have something to do with that? Anyway here is my modified code: http://jsfiddle.net/Uen6z/

Comment: I don't think your webmail client should matter unless they've forgotten to implement the Date header which seems far-fetched. You can check that very easily by changing the $email_to value to a different email address. Can you paste the PHP data of the email (just print to screen and copy/paste) as well as the received email raw data somewhere and post a link to both?

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have another domain email adress, and i cant get it to work to my gmail or hotmail. I did manage to get the date and time correctly on the message itself, but the header date is still blank. Here is my new php code: http://jsfiddle.net/kCfSM/ , and here is a print screen of what i receive on my email: http://www.mediafire.com/view/febzimuuna1n532/php_mail_test.jpg#

And sorry for ask but what do you mean by email raw data? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work with gmail or hotmail? If the email is sending, they're receiving. It might get stuck in spam though. Try and find it. If you can't, send the email to punk_monkey64@mailinator.com and let me know when you do. I'm going to need to setup my own server with a mailing engine to try and debug your script. I'll reply soon with my results.

Comment: I tried already sending to gmail and hotmail, it doesn't receive anything, not even in spam, but i always get the success message. I already sent a test email to your adress. I don't want you to go to so much trouble for this...but if its okay ill be waiting for your reply.